Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.3.11:build-frontend (build-frontend) on Maven Project with Vaadin 23 version
Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.3.11:build-frontend (build-frontend) on Maven Project containing Vaadin 23 version:
Note: I am trying to migrate Vaadin 7 (maven) project to Vaadin 23.
ERROR:
ERROR Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.3.11:build-frontend (build-frontend) on project mf: Could not execute build-fron tend goal: Error occured during goal execution: ERROR ERROR   Failed to find the following files: ERROR       - ./components/dd-vertical-layout.js
ERROR       - ./components/custom-media-query.js
ERROR       - ./components/common.js
ERROR ERROR   Locations searched were:
ERROR       - META-INF/frontendin included JARs
ERROR       -META-INF/resources/frontendin included JARs
ERROR ERROR   Please, double check that those files exist. If you use a custom directory for your resource files instead of defaultfrontend` folder the n make sure you it's correctly configured (e.g. set 'vaadin.frontend.frontend.folder' property) [ERROR]
[ERROR] Please run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.3.11:build-frontend (build-frontend) on project mf: Could not execute build-frontend goal at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not execute build-frontend goal at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.maven.BuildFrontendMojo.execute (BuildFrontendMojo.java:102) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException:
Error occured during goal execution:
Failed to find the following files:'

./components/dd-vertical-layout.js

./components/custom-media-query.js

./components/common.js` POM:


POM contains following dependencies and plugins related to Vaadin:
Main Project POM:
` <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>     
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>prepare-frontend</id>
    <goals>
    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
    <id>build-frontend</id>
    <goals>
    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
   </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>`

Child POM Vaadin Plugin:

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <frontendDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN</frontendDirectory>
    <generatedFolder>${project.basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources/frontend</generatedFolder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


On doing Maven clean install, the following errors must not occur and build must be successful.

ERROR: Failed to find the following files: 
- ./components/dd-vertical-layout.js 
- ./components/custom-media-query.js 
- ./components/common.js

Thanks in advanced.


You have different Vaadin version in the vaadin-maven-plugin, vaadin-core and vaadin. This is very likely to cause problems.

Tried with all same versions, i.e., 23.1.2 for all Vaadin-core, vaadin-maven-plugin, vaadin, but still same error is occuring.

Try last free 23 version: 23.4.1. And use
 

com.vaadin
vaadin-bom
${vaadin.version}
pom
import




Tried with suggested version, but still getting sam error.

Do you have the three files in your "frontend/components" folder?

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>     
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

This is wrong. You should define vaadin-bom in a <dependencyManagement> block with a version number. The rest of the dependencies should not have a version number, as the BOM's purpose is to supply those. Take a look at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/building-apps/project-structure/single-module#pom-structure for more details.
You should also not define both vaadin and vaadin-core in a single project; vaadin-core is a subset of vaadin; vaadin-core contains only free components and vaadin contains the full set including commercially licensed components.
